# How does Android Back Navigation works?

Tags: android, back-button, lifecycle

I have a problem understanding the difference between backButton issued as the Hardware button, and backButton issued as a super.onBackPressed() from the Activity (i.e. from menu android.R.id.home).

In the case of Hardware backButton the data in my Activity are initiated immediately and in the exact state which Activity hold before leaving.
In the case of on super.onBackPressed() it seems like the former Activity gets finished, since the data needs to be initiated from the scratch.

Tried studying the lifecycle but found nothing interesting for this usecase.

How can I mimic behavior of the Hardware Button, which would allow me to retain state of the Activity?
Can prepare some demo code, but I hope I provided good enough high level description.

Comment: Read the documentation: [Up vs Back](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back).

Comment: I guess it is not guaranteed that in case of hardware back button it will keep state of previous activity every time , I think still it is better to save state just before leaving current activity in bundle and restore it when you come back.